# Oracle Apex: how to exclude a selected PopUp LOV row from its Query and refresh it dynamiclly

Tags: popup, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

i had an IG, it has a PopUp LOV column to select value, the LOV Query is in Shared Component. is it possible if user select '01-My First Row' from LOV this will not available in next row or disabled to select and similar for other selected values? if yes, how it can done? filtering LOV Query on runtime refrencing selected value(s) in IG or anything else? help needed.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to decide if a value from LOV is selected before it is submitted to the server-side (before saving the IG in that case), you need to handle that using client-side code(javascript).

As an idea, you can create a dynamic action that will execute a Javascript code on LOV value selection.

In that Javascript code, use

```
var widget = apex.region('yourgridID').widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews', 'grid');
var model = grid.model;
model.forEach(function(r) {
  var record = r;
  console.log(record);
})
```

Then you can observe the record on your browser's console to see the column value when an item of LOV is selected.
Then you would need to use `JQUERY` for disabling the LOV list values.

Comment: thanks @cengiz sevimli, but i don't know JS and how to for JQuery, please help for disabling the LOV's selected values at runtime before saving. regards

Comment: copy your code and paste in DA of PopUp LOV item on Change event, Action = Execute JavaScript code, replaced 'yourgridID' with my IG Static ID and run to check in Console but it is showing error when page rendered. in Console there are 2 errors. 1) Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  and 2) Uncaught TypeError: apex.da.initDaEventList is not a function. added ) in last after } it is not showing error. how i can check the data in Console it is showing?

Comment: I edited my answer, could you check again? @AhmedHaroon

Comment: yes, you added " ) " in code which already done and mentioned in my previous comment " added ) in last after } " and also mentioned that " how i can check the data in Console " as i don't know the JavaScript and JQuery. there are various things in output in Console and i really failed to understand.

Comment: this is what i can see in Console: Array(3) [ "t1000", {…}, {} ]
0: "t1000"
1: Object { v: "1", d: "Red" }
2: Object {  }
length: 3
<prototype>: Array []